# Is it possible to have backend written in Haskell and frontend with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, haskell, yesod

currently I'm working on this project (https://github.com/Giegling/addressbook) and for the backend I use Node.js with Express framework, for the frontend Angularjs. Is it possible to "translate" the backend to Haskell without touching the frontend? If it's possible, which framework should I use? (Yesod, scotty...)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible. To see an example, look at this: https://github.com/snoyberg/yesod-js (Although I'm not sure how updated angular is in the repo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your server simply exposes a HTTP API to your angular app. You can implement that functionality in any web framework (or even without a framework) in pretty much any language.

Yesod is probably the most popular and well documented Haskell framework (personal opinion), so I guess you can start with that.

Comment: Be aware that if you're just learning programming, Haskell is probably not a good place to start. It's a beatiful language, but might be pretty hard for a beginner. And learning a framework like Yesod on top of that will make it even harder.

Comment: @ralh Your mileage (and the OPs) may vary, but anecdotally Haskell is relatively easier for absolute beginners than for people with some programming experience, as in the first case there are less habits you have to unlearn or suspend. In any case, it might indeed be useful for a beginner to play a bit with a microframework like Scotty or Spock before moving on to a fully-featured one like Yesod.